# Advertising on free version of Openshift?

Tags: openshift

Is it okay to put online advertising on a website running on Openshift, even if I'm using the free plan? I'm planning to buy a separate domain, but keep using the free server. I'm planning to use Google Adsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The only limitation the free service has is that its limited on resources.

> The Free Services may be used without charge up to the thresholds set
>   forth at https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing. If You require
>   Services in excess of the Free Services or exceed the thresholds
>   referenced in the previous sentence, you must upgrade to the Paid
>   Services and pay the associated Fees.

https://www.openshift.com/legal/services_agreement